# How to write a scala program to find semantic matching between the attributes in two tables

Tags: database, scala, preprocessor

I'm working on pre-processing techniques, in which I am concentrating on semantic matching between attributes of two tables. How to write a scala program to do such semantic matching?

Consider I am having two tables A and B

A has attributes (`employee_id`, `DOB`, `salary`)

B has attributes  (`emp_id`, `data_of_birth`, `sal`)

I need to find most matching attributes in two tables, so that my output table will not have duplicate columns *(example: emp_id and employee_id should be found similar and considered as single cloumn).*

Comment: Do something like `join` on tables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Scala collection has intersection, which will get the common elements of two sets.

`ex: collecationA.intersect(collectionB)`
however if you are coming from spark api, the schema level comparison we can perform(same as intersect )operator

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Intersection will get common values in two tables. My problem is actually to compare attributes (not values) of two different tables and identify the matching attributes. Can you help me with suggesting something like ngram matcher or any other available techniques for semantic matching.